# Only list certain tables to list of tables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I want to list only certain tables in my book on the List of Tables using `\listoftables` command, especially ones that are captioned. I have labelled tables that are captioned and not the ones that are not captioned. How can I tackle this problem? Say, I have 15 tables that I want to list among 100 tables.

I used empty `\caption{}` for uncaptioned tables just for displaying table numbers.

Comment: Don't use the `table` environment for the ones you don't want listed?

Comment: I have a problem following your problem. A `\caption` in a table gets put into the LoT, a table without a `\caption` does not get into the LoT.

Comment: Oh wait, that is true. I actually used empty `\caption{}` for uncaptioned tables just for the purpose of displaying table numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's assume you want an alternate captioning command that only prints a table number, but no caption and doesn't go into the list of tables.

Let's look at how `\caption` is defined, part is in the LaTeX kernel:

```
\def\caption{%
   \ifx\@captype\@undefined
     \@latex@error{\noexpand\caption outside float}\@ehd
     \expandafter\@gobble
   \else
     \refstepcounter\@captype
     \expandafter\@firstofone
   \fi
   {\@dblarg{\@caption\@captype}}%
}
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
```

and part lives in the document class (the base classes are all pretty similar in their implementation):

```
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
```

This is going to be fairly easy to simplify for your needs. We don't need to worry about dealing with optional arguments or any arguments at all. Instead, we'll create a `\nocaption` command which just prints the table number and nothing else. As an added bonus, our formatting can be a little better than what's on offer with `\caption{}`.

First step is we'll keep the check to make sure we're inside a float when we call `\caption`:

```
\def\nocaption{%
   \if\@captype\@undefined
       \@latex@error{\noexpand\nocaption outside float}\@ehd
   \else
      \refstepcounter\@captype
```

There's no need to worry about the stuff surrounding parsing arguments, but we will have everything wrapped in an `\if`…`\fi` so that we can recover ok from an error.

We don't need anything else from `\caption` or `\@caption` here. All we need to do is center the table number with the appropriate spacing

```
      \vskip\abovecaptionskip
      \hb#@xt@\hsize{\hfil\normalsize \@nameuse{\@captype} 
          \@nameuse{the\@captype}\hfil}
      \vskip\belowcaptionskip
```

`\@nameuse` is an internal macro in LaTeX that lets us access a command by name (it's identical to `\csname`…`\endcsname`. The kernel is inconsistent about choosing `\@nameuse` over `\csname`…`\endcsname` for reasons that I suspect no one knows but is most likely just different ages of the code).

Finally we can close out our `\if`…`\fi` and our definition:

```
    \fi
  }
```

Now you can replace all your `\caption{}`s with `\nocaption` and get your desired output.